# Operations on strings in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

I have a program that makes operations on strings and this is the principal function of one of those operations.  This works perfectly, but it is not efficient:

```
private void printString(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
    int numerOfStrings = 0;
    int numberOfletters = 0;
    String toPrint = operations.get(1);
    outOfLoop: for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        String[] toFind = set.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < toFind.length; k++) {
        if (toPrint.equals(toFind[k])) {
            String[] splited = set.get(i).split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < splited.length; j++) {
            numberOfletters += splited[j].length();
            }
            numerOfStrings = splited.length;
            break outOfLoop;
        }
      }  
    }
    System.out.println(numerOfStrings + " " + numberOfletters);
}
```

Explanation:

This function takes as parameter an `arrayList` of operations, and an `arrayList` of set:

1. For the `arrayList` of `operations`, I get always a specific position, so I don't iterate.  It is always \$O(1)\$.
2. For the `arrayList` of set, I have to iterate, or rather, as I think of that to proceed:

   For example, if have as operation `print foo`, I have to do these steps:

   - First of all, I have to find where foo is:

     - Inside `set`, I can have this situation:

       ```
       position 1 : {car tree hotel}
       ...
       position n : {foo lemon coffee}
       ```
     - When I find the string `foo`, I have to print the number of strings inside that position and the number of letters of each string, so in this case, I will print:

       3(number of strings) 14(sum of number of letters)

My program works as well as this function, but it is a nasty and inefficient solution.  How can I improve the efficiency of my program?

Comment: what if you search for `oo` should he also give position n?(your code do but I suspect that may not be the case). Also your use case says number of letters of **each** string. Shouldn't be that 3 - 4 - 6?

Comment: sum of number of letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first do a review without getting into the logic of the method.
Before I start making changes I've commented some *smelly* places in your original code:

```
//Try to use the most generic type in your arguments. You don't really need an ArrayList<>
//a List<> will suffice.
private void printString(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {     
    int numerOfStrings = 0;
    int numberOfletters = 0;
    //why take a list parameter when you only use one value (the second element?!)
    String toPrint = operations.get(1); 
    outOfLoop: for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        String[] toFind = set.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < toFind.length; k++) {
            if (toPrint.equals(toFind[k])) {
                // duplicated work: toFind == splitted
                String[] splited = set.get(i).split(" "); 
                for (int j = 0; j < splited.length; j++) {
                    numberOfletters += splited[j].length();
                }
                numerOfStrings = splited.length;
                //goto is considered evil
                //Besides, goto to label is not neccessary here.
                //A simple `break` would suffice
                break outOfLoop;  
            }
        }
    }
    //you should return the results and let the caller of the method
    //decide what to do with them
    System.out.println(numerOfStrings + " " + numberOfletters);
}
```

So, in the first refactoring iteration I've ended up with:

```
public static class Result {
    public final int numerOfStrings;
    public final int numberOfletters;

    public Result(int numerOfStrings, int numberOfletters) {
        this.numerOfStrings = numerOfStrings;
        this.numberOfletters = numberOfletters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numerOfStrings + " " + numberOfletters;
    }
}

private Result process(String word, List<String> set) {
    int numerOfStrings = 0;
    int numberOfletters = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        String[] toFind = set.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < toFind.length; k++) {
            if (word.equals(toFind[k])) {
                String[] splited = set.get(i).split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < splited.length; j++) {
                    numberOfletters += splited[j].length();
                }
                numerOfStrings = splited.length;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return new Result(numerOfStrings, numberOfletters);
}


@Test
public void run() throws Exception {
    Result result = process("foo", Arrays.asList("car tree hotel","foo lemon coffe"));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This keeps the method logic intact, but fixes all the issues I mentioned in the comments.

But actually I think the method could be a lot simpler:

```
private Result process(String word, Iterable<String> set) {
    for (String string : set) {
        if(string.contains(word)) {
            //" +" is a regex patten for "one or more spaces"  
            int numberOfWords = string.trim().split(" +").length;
            int numberOfLetters = string.replace(" ", "").length();
            return new Result(numberOfWords,  numberOfLetters );
        }
    }
    return new Result(0, 0);
}
```

This version is more readable, but could be optimized for performance. As always with performance you should first check if optimizing here would make any impact on the application as a whole. Sacrificing readability might not be worth it.

Optimizations might include:

1. avoid new string creation using `trim()`
2. avoid new string array creation using `split()`
3. avoid new string creation using `replace()`
4. avoid iterating over `string` multiple times - count letters and words while looking for `word` (instead of `contains`)

Comment: @the second your solution you said `This version is more readable, but could be optimized for performance`, i think is not possible to avoid iterate,or not?

Comment: EDIT: Answer added at the end

Comment: oh i have understand this,but this sentence confused me,`but could be optimized for performance`.

Comment: "goto is considered evil" - nice, inaccurate, unexplained, irrelevant, and generally misleading comment to add. No 'goto' in java, named breaks are fine and not evil, and changing it to a simple 'break' instead of a named break may not even have any efficiency impact whatsoever!

Comment: `string.contains(word)` does not perform equally. (`"this is some test".contains("so")` is true, while "so" it not one of the string split on " "). I would add boundaries and use a regex. (`string.matches(".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*")` for example, though that would not work if the word contains some special characters. a combination of `startsWith`, `endWith` and `contains` with padding spaces would work but be more verbose)

Comment: @njzk2 `Arrays.asList(string.trim().split(" +")).contains(word)` might even be best as it directly matches the intended logic.

Comment: @njzk2 you' re right, without this `(string.matches(".*\\b" + word + "\\b.*")` the solution of rzymek is not complete.

Answer (score 3):

This will be a code-style focused review, as the other answers didn't address that yet:

#### Indentation:

your indentation style is either unconventional or got f*cked up by the SE markdown, either way:

1. Indentation standard step is 4 spaces. (you are using 2)
2. Block contained items are indented one step. Block delimiters are not indented.

Applying this to your code it becomes something like this:

```
private void printString(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
    int numberOfStrings = 0;
    int numberOfLetters = 0;
    String toPrint = operations.get(1);
    outOfLoop: for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        String[] toFind = set.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < toFind.length; k++) {
            if (toPrint.equals(toFind[k])) {
                String[] splited =set.get(i).split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < splited.length; j++) {
                     numberOfLetters += splited[j].length();
                }
                numberOfStrings = splited.length;
                break outOfLoop;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfStrings + " " + numberOfLetters);
}
```

#### Code-Smells

*sniff-sniff*

1. this looks a lot like [arrow-code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), that needs to be flattened.
    **Solution:** Introduce methods to do stuff for you. `countLetters(String s)` would be a start.
2. `splited` and `numberOfletters` are a little off (orthographically and casing). "correct would be" `splitted` and `numberOfLetters`.
3. `System.out.println();` is almost **never a good sign**. Your method does two things here. It analyzes the two strings and then prints the result. Methods should always do just **one thing**. This is called [Single Responsibility Principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) I would expect a method `printString` to take a String and print it to some output.
4. `String toPrint = operations.get(1);` This one is a candidate for an `ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException`. Keep in mind, that operations does not necessarily contain more than one Item! As you only use a single string either way, you should just give `toPrint` in the parameters directly.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a similar solution to @rzymek's.

Variables named `numberOf…` would be better named `…Count`.

I've renamed other variables to have more meaningful names, such as `requiredWord`, `sentence`, and `sentences`.  If you are indeed dealing with words and sentences, you'll want to handle delimiters such as punctuation.  In that case, a `BreakIterator.getWordInstance()` would come in handy.

For clarity, I've split part of the function into a helper that examines just one sentence.

The search for the required word happens while processing each word, such that there is only one pass needed.

```
public static class WordAndCharCount {
    public final int wordCount, charCount;
    public static final WordAndCharCount NOT_FOUND = new WordAndCharCount(0, 0);

    public WordAndCharCount(int wordCount, int charCount) {
        this.wordCount = wordCount;
        this.charCount = charCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.wordCount + " " + this.charCount;
    }
}

private static WordAndCharCount examine(String requiredWord, Iterable<String> sentences) {
    for (String sentence : sentences) {
        WordAndCharCount r = examine(requiredWord, sentence);
        if (r != null) {
            return r;
        }
    }
    return WordAndCharCount.NOT_FOUND;
}

private static WordAndCharCount examine(String requiredWord, String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    boolean foundWord = false;
    int charCount = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        charCount += word.length();
        if (foundWord || word.equals(requiredWord)) {
            foundWord = true;
        }
    }
    return foundWord ? new WordAndCharCount(words.length, charCount) : null;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution, i will try also your solution.